# Enabling APC cache takes down website

Tags: centos5, cache, alternative-php-cache

I have a VPS running on centos 5 with 2 GB ram. I run a IP.Board forum on that server. Recently my server was hacked and I had to format the disk and start again. I was using APC cache before and it was running fine. But now when I enable it the forum goes offline. I am at my wits end. Please help me to get it working. Lemme know if I need to provide more info about my server. Regards

I am using the following configuration I found on a StackOverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570131/optimize-apc-caching

```
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1

; I would try 32M per WP install, go from there
apc.shm_size=128M

; Relative to approx cached PHP files,
apc.num_files_hint=512

; Relative to approx WP size W/ APC Object Cache Backend, 
apc.user_entries_hint=4096

apc.ttl=7200
apc.use_request_time=1
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.filters
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.file_update_protection=2
apc.enable_cli=0
apc.max_file_size=2M

;This should be used when you are finished with PHP file changes.
;As you must clear the APC cache to recompile already cached files.
;If you are still developing, set this to 1.
apc.stat=0

apc.stat_ctime=0
apc.canonicalize=1
apc.write_lock=1
apc.report_autofilter=0
apc.rfc1867=0
apc.rfc1867_prefix =upload_
apc.rfc1867_name=APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_freq=0
apc.rfc1867_ttl=3600

;This MUST be 0, WP can have errors otherwise!
apc.include_once_override=0

apc.lazy_classes=0
apc.lazy_functions=0
apc.coredump_unmap=0
apc.file_md5=0
apc.preload_path
```

I used the same tutorial to install apc as before. It can be found at this link

http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/08/how-to-install-apc-alternative-php-cache-on-centos-5-6/

Comment: What do your server's error logs say?

Comment: @ceejayoz you mean the error_log in /var/log/httpd ..?

Comment: there it says:
/usr/lib/php/modules/xcache.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension

Comment: Nothing to do with APC, then. You're loading the `xcache` module but it's not installed properly.

Comment: @ceejayoz but everything is OK when I turn apc.enabled=0